# How can I have multiple buttons in a table

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Currently I can select Edit go to the form and select deselect the 'Monitoring Active' option. The status is shown via a Twitter-Bootstrap label, as seen in the `status_tag` helper.
What I can't figure out is how to make the label a clickable button that will change the state right there.

The view code:

```
<!-- <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p> -->
<h3>All Sites</h3>
<div><%= pluralize(@sites.size, 'sites') %> found</div>
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Site</th>
      <th>Hostname</th>
      <th>Monitoring Active</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% num = 0 %>
    <% @sites.each do |site| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= num += 1 %></td>
        <td><%= site.site_name  %></td>
        <td><%= link_to site.host_name, site.host_name, :target => "_blank" %></td>
        <td><%= status_tag(site.monitor) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to("Show", {:controller => :show, :action => 'site', :id => site.id}, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-xs') %></td>
        <td><%= link_to("Edit", {:action => 'edit', :id => site.id}, class: 'btn btn-info btn-xs') %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The helper 'status_tag' code

```
def status_tag(bool, options = {})
  options[:true_text]   ||= 'Active'
  options[:false_text]  ||= 'Disabled'
  options[:true_label]  ||= 'label-success'
  options[:false_label] ||= 'label-warning'

  if bool
    content_tag(:span, options[:true_text], class: "btn #{options[:true_label]} btn-xs")
  else
    content_tag(:span, options[:false_text], class: "btn #{options[:false_label]} btn-xs")
  end
end
```

Comment: To change the state in place you would need some JS to make the AJAX call and then update the label from the response. Also `nil` is a falsey value in ruby so the first line of your `status_tag` method is unnecessary as it will evaluate the same either way.

Comment: I feared that. And radio buttons or tick boxes? Will edit out that first line. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using a robust javascript frontend, the only way to do this is to have the "Monitoring Active" button send a request to a rails route, resulting in a status change on the server side. Your controller should then redirect to this same page, but now `site.monitor` will have a different value than before.

This is not a great way of doing things, as it requires a full back and forth request to your rails server. Using javascript to change the status on the frontend by manipulating the DOM would be far less time consuming. What you need to remember is that by the time you are looking at your site in the browser, that erb ruby code no longer exists. It has been compiled. You can't expect it to do anything *after* it's been served. See this to learn more about why redirecting is not good for performance:

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/mobile#AvoidRedirects

**But to answer your question:**

If you want multiple buttons on your site, just use multiple forms. You can use form_for, or make the forms yourself. In each form, use:

`<input type="hidden" value="whatever you want to send to your server"/>`.

And simply use a `<button>` with the desired text for each.

Forms with hidden inputs will not show anything but the button. Put your desired action in the form `action` property.